# Histogram using plot in Pandas - set x label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

Dataframe:

```
Horror films released in 2019
Title           Director            Country             Year
3 from Hell     Rob Zombie          United States   2019
Bliss           Joe Begos           United States   2019
Bedeviled       The Vang Brothers   United States   2016
Creep 2         Patrick Brice       United States   2017
Brightburn      David Yarovesky     United States   2019
Delirium        Dennis Iliadis      Ireland         2018
Child's Play    Lars Klevberg       United States   2019
The Conjuring 2 James Wan           United States   2016
Bloodlands      Steven Kastrissios  Albania         2017
Bird Box        Susanne Bier        United States   2017
```

need to plot a histogram showing the number of titles released over the years using Pandas plot function

code:

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename)
group = df.groupby('Year').count()[['Title']]
new_df = grouped.reset_index()
xtick=newdf['Year'].tolist()
width = newdf.Year[1] - newdf.Year[0]
newdf.iloc[:,1:2].plot(kind='bar', width=width)
```

Cannot figure out a way to label x axis with values from the Year column, also unsure if my approach is correct.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a bar chart, not a histogram, because you have discrete/categorical variables (years). And you say "kind=bar" in your plot statement, so you are on the right track. Try this to see if it works for you. I forced the y-axis to be integers since you are looking for counts, but that is optional.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

title = [ 'Movie1','Movie2','Movie3',
        'Movie4','Movie5','Movie6',
        'Movie7','Movie8','Movie9',
]

year = [2019,2019,2018,
        2017,2019,2018,
        2019,2017,2018
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(title, year)), 
                  columns =['Title', 'Year']
                 )

print(df)
group = df.groupby('Year').count()[['Title']]\
        .rename(columns={'Title': 'No. of Movies'})\
        .reset_index()
print(group)

ax = group.plot.bar(x='Year', rot=0)
ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(integer=True)
plt.show()
```

```
    Title  Year
0  Movie1  2019
1  Movie2  2019
2  Movie3  2018
3  Movie4  2017
4  Movie5  2019
5  Movie6  2018
6  Movie7  2019
7  Movie8  2017
8  Movie9  2018
```

```
   Year  No. of Movies
0  2017              2
1  2018              3
2  2019              4
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The api offers a few different ways to do this (not a great thing imo).  Here is one way to get what you want:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
group = df.groupby('Year').count()[['Title']]
df2 = group.reset_index()
df2.plot(kind='bar', x="Year", y="Title")
```

Or, even more concisely:

```
df.value_counts("Year").plot(kind="bar")
```

Note that in the second case, you're creating a bar plot from a Series object.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
df.groupby('Year').Title.count().plot(kind='bar')
```

Output

[image]